Exceeding 6 mins execution limit due to calculating formulas
I used the "Query" function in 3 tabs to create tables which sources data from another 3 tabs. I want to use Apps Script to pull data from a url and update the source tabs. However, when updating, the spreadsheet calculates the formula for a long time before moving to the next line in the script, which then exceeds the 6 minutes time limit.
Is there any way I can speed up or pause the calculation of formulas?
I tried using Index Match instead of Query, but it does not make a difference.

How many formulas? Have you tried arrayformulas?

There is no setting that stops formulas from recalculating when their parameter ranges change. You can alter the formulas programmatically so that they are inactive, but it usually makes more sense to fix the issues that cause the performance problem in the first place. See my spreadsheet optimization tips.

the spreadsheet calculates the formula for a long time before moving to the next line in the script

Modify the script so that it gets all data rows in one go with Range.getValues(), calculates all the results using Array.map() and friends, and then writes the final results to the spreadsheet with Range.setValues().
See Apps Script best practices and custom function best practices.

Thanks, the main purpose is for me to look up each value in a source tab to present it in a custom table format in another sheet. This is why each cell of the table has a query formula, summing to ~12000 formulas.

Use arrayformula(ifna(vlookup())) or similar instead of repeating a query() 12,000 times. See What is the XY problem?
